# How to make a legacy system heavily reliant on Entity Framework more testable?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing

We have a fairly large system (~1m lines) which is heavily reliant on Entity Framework 6. This means our DbContext is passed around and used everywhere.

We also have lots of "unit" tests, that are using an actual SQL Server database. Each machine that runs tests has a dedicated database which gets wiped and set up with needed data before running each test.

This is of course not ideal in terms of speed, maintainability, ease of use, etc.

My end goal is to make all of our unit tests (~5k tests) not use an actual database, but a mock of some sort. I know this process is not going to be easy but I also want it to be as less painful as possible.

How can I make my tests faster and more unit scoped?

Comment: *Guidelines and thoughts*... please read the help about the kind of question that fit here.

Comment: "~1m lines" - that's not "fairly large", that's *massive*.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one option here, and that is to make an in memory system. The unfortunate part of in memory is that it does not merge well with entity framework, like at all.

All of the mocks for Entity Framework are suggested as being done with mock databases, which you already have setup.

So the good news is that you can do it in memory on your own! The bad news is that you can do it, in memory, on your own.

You are going to have to create a mirror implementation of Entity Framework which works only on an in memory set of information. In many ways this is similar to event driven in memory cache systems and the benefit you will get out of creating a custom implementation for mocking in memory would be that you can easily port it over to support caching your database information and also allowing an interface for querying that information.

This will expose features such as event driven push technologies (SignalR) for live data. It will also take a lot of time. If the development time required to implement an in memory mock of entity framework is less than the time lost due to waiting for tests to complete in the mock database then it may be worth it.

Comment: Implementing a provider looks complicated, but I thought about something similar that might be easier. I will make the DbContext implement an interface and use this interface all over the system. In our tests I'll replace the real instances of DbContext with mock ones. Sounds feasible?

Answer (score 0):

> We also have lots of "unit" tests, that are using an actual SQL Server database. Each machine that runs tests has a dedicated database which gets wiped and set up with needed data before running each test.
>
> This is of course not ideal in terms of speed, maintainability, ease of use, etc.
>
> My end goal is to make all of our unit tests (~5k tests) not use an actual database, but a mock of some sort. I know this process is not going to be easy but I also want it to be as less painful as possible.

I disagree with your conclusion. I recommend you keep the existing dedicated testing database, I actually think it's an excellent idea to test with an actual database because it will reveal any data-layer issues, such as if someone makes a change to the database schema without it being reflected in your EF Entity classes. The EF itself is fairly well tested so having code-coverage of EF-generated classes is a fool's errand in my personal opinion, and the disconnect between entity-classes and the database is probably the #1 area where things can (and will) go wrong.

I understand your performance concerns with using this approach, certainly there are potential optimizations to be had, such as not resetting the database before running every test (perhaps have the tests assume the database is in a known "good state" before starting) and only reset it after the test suite is completed.

Comment: The performance bottlenecks in our tests are the calls to the DB in the tests themselves. I want our developers to get a fast feedback when they break tests, and with the current speed this is not possible.
Resetting the DB once per test suite will break most of our tests (which rely on a clean DB), and will require us to manually fix all of them.